# colspan adjust on clicked of button

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is when I clicked on "span cell 1" button the colspan is done properly, but the head td's are extended and the table layout is disturbed as in table size increases. Cant it manage the remaining column?

If I click in span cell 1 button then first td is span in first 3 header. then remaining td's should be in one header.

```js
function function1() {
  document.getElementById("myTableHeader").colSpan = "3";
}
function function2() {
  document.getElementById("myTd1").colSpan = "3";
}
function function3() {
  document.getElementById("myTd2").colSpan = "2";
}
function function4() {
  document.getElementById("myTableHeader").colSpan = "1";
  document.getElementById("myTd1").colSpan = "1";
  document.getElementById("myTd2").colSpan = "1";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th align="center" bgcolor="blue" style="color:white;">First Header</th>
    <th id="myTableHeader" bgcolor="green" style="color:white;" width="140">Second Header</th>
    <th align="center" bgcolor="red" style="color:white;" width="140">Third Header</th>
    <th align="center" bgcolor="gray" style="color:white;" width="140">Fourth Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="myTd1">Cell 1 content</td>
    <td>Cell 2 content</td>
    <td id="myTd2">Cell 3 content</td>
    <td>Cell 4 content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" name="S1" value="Span Second Header" onClick="function1();">
<input type="button" name="S2" value="Span Cell 1" onClick="function2();">
<input type="button" name="S3" value="Span Cell 3" onClick="function3();">
<input type="button" name="S4" value="Restore" onClick="function4();">
```

Answer (score 0):

> > but the ahead td's are extend.and table layout is disturb

This is how it should be. You need to delete the cell, which space would be occupied by spanning cell.

You may play with colspan/rowspan properties editing HTML in your editor, not with javascript, in order to better understand, how it works.